# Batch - Random Number thing

Tags: random, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that makes up a random DOB.

```
@echo off
title Random DOB Generator!
echo Working...
echo.
:loop
set dd=%random%
if "%dd%" GTR 31 goto loop
if "%dd%" LSS 1 goto loop
:loop2
echo %dd%/??/????
echo.
:loop2a
set mm=%random%
if "%mm%" GTR 12 goto loop2a
if "%mm%" LSS 1 goto loop2a
:loop3
echo %dd%/%mm%/????
echo.
:loop3a
set yyyy=%random%
if "%yyyy%" GTR 2000 goto loop3a
if "%yyyy%" LSS 1900 goto loop3a
:win
echo.
echo Result: %dd%/%mm%/%yyyy%
pause > nul
exit
```

But it doesn't do anything, it just sits there. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is how you are generating your random numbers.

`%random%` returns a number between 0 and 32767, so trying to generate a number between 1 and 31, 1 and 12, and 1900 and 2000 is going to take some time.

It isn't doing nothing, it's just taking so long to find matching numbers that it seems like that.

You can use a bit of maths to find a number between a certain range, so you don't have to wait.

```
@echo off
title Random DOB Generator!
echo Working...
echo.
set /a dd=%random% * 31 / 32768 + 1
echo %dd%/??/????
echo.
set /a mm=%random% * 12 / 32768 + 1
echo %dd%/%mm%/????
echo.
set /a yyyy=%random% * (2000 - 1900 + 1) / 32768 + 1900
echo.
echo Result: %dd%/%mm%/%yyyy%
pause >nul
exit
```

If you took off `@echo off` from your original script I think you would see how many numbers it was generating to find a match :)

Comment: You can also use modular arithmetic with the modulo operator `%`.  This way there is no need to specify the max random value of `32768`. Just specify the max value desired `31` and this will return `1 to 31`.  **`:)`**  `set /a Value=(%Random% % 31) + 1`  To use a custom min and max value range use the following setup. `set /a Value=(%Random% % (2000 - 1900)) + (1900 + 1)`  or for simplicity  `set /a Value=(%Random% % 100) + 1901`

Comment: No. The number returned by %random% is (supposedly) evenly distributed in the range 0-32767. When you divide it by 32768 and multiply by the desired range, the new number have the same distribution in the new range. The modulo of %random% by any number have an unknow distribution, but of course it is worse than the original. This mean that you get repeated numbers more frequently.